# JavaScript object representing electric circuit

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to draw electric circuits based on a JavaScript object on p5.js. The structure of the object is a tree, a node is either a parallel connection or a series connection and a leaf is an electrical component. Here is an example :

This :

```html
let circuit = {
  type: "series",
  comp: [
    {
      type: "parallel",
      comp: [
        {
          type: "series",
          comp: [
            {
              type: "parallel",
              comp: [
                { type: "res", name: "R_1" },
                { type: "res", name: "R_2" },
                { type: "res", name: "R_3" },
                { type: "res", name: "R_4" },
                
              ]
            },
            { type: "ind", name: "L" }
          ]
        },
        { type: "res", name : 'r_0' }
      ]
    },
    { type: "cap", name: "C" }
  ]
}
```

Should be drawn as this (using european drawing system)

[image: Drawing based on JS object]

I already have the basic functions to draw electrical components given the start point and end point, what I want is a way to define where all the start points and end points of each component are and a way to link component together (using p5's line function).

Any help would be greatly apreciated!

Comment: Your insistence to use a tree seems misguided.

Comment: But it is an interesting problem nonetheless. Im not too certain about your data structure however. It makes a kind of sense but its going to be hard to build algorithms around that. Instead a tree like any graph is simply an array (in the collection sense of the term) of nodes. Not an array of an array of an array of nodes. The interconnections or structure should be defined via the "links" between them.

Comment: @GetSet I agree with you but storing only the links between components would make it hard to know what component is supposed to be to the left or the right.

Comment: Right now it seems that you are looking at the structure from the perspective of where the current is *going*. But if you look at as where the current is *coming from* then your graph will have inherent direction, that can be up to the rendering algorithm you devise on positioning the components. You could make your renderer for example, simulate an "organization hierarchy" with options to rotate on 90 degree increments to achieve the desired orientation.

Comment: Ultimately if you go with a pure graph as I suggested, you could have an intermediate step in play that translates your collection of nodes to the tree array of an array structure you posted. And then render from that.